# How do I limit an Excel formula in a row to a specific range of data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, range

In an Excel workbook I have ranges, e.g. from ABA through ABS in one cell, and would like to decouple each them and add every code between those, like on the picture. No VBA method though.
[image]

Managed to create a matrix ([file here](https://bayfiles.com/15Sfz2Ecxf/Book2_xlsx)) with range limits (green cells - formula 1) and filled in every code within those ranges (orange cells - formula 2).

What I don't like in this solution are the excessive values after range limit (blue cells in ex. row 5) because of formula 2 not being advanced enough. Would like to get rid of those blue values and have those cells left empty.
[image]

Looking for a concept to tackle this one as I'm outta ideas right now. It would have to be a formula 2 modification of some sort. Can anybody advise how could I make the formula stop at a particular range limit (e.g. ABS)?

Comment: Not everyone will download a file from an unknown source, also, your question becomes useless to others once that link goes dead. Please include a minimal reproducible example (and your formulas!) in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- Your 'from' code is always three characters, beginning with AB
- Your 'to' code is always three characters, beginning with AB
- The range goes from a single upper case alphabetical character (e.g. A) to another single upper case alphabetical character (e.g. S)
- You have a recent version of Excel and access to the `LET` and `SEQUENCE` functions

Then you can do it like this:

[image]

To return the sequence of results on rows, you use this formula, as shown in cell B1 in the image above:

```
=LET(from,MID($A1,3,1),to,RIGHT($A1,1),"AB"&CHAR(SEQUENCE(CODE(to)-CODE(from)+1,1,CODE(from),1)))
```

To return the sequence of results on columns, you use this formula, as shown in cell C1 in the image above:

```
=LET(from,MID($A1,3,1),to,RIGHT($A1,1),"AB"&CHAR(SEQUENCE(1,CODE(to)-CODE(from)+1,CODE(from),1)))
```

1. Let the name 'from' be equal to the third character in the range (i.e. A)
2. Let the name 'to' be equal to the right-most character in the range (i.e. S)
3. The `CODE` function converts a character to the numerical representation of that character. The code for A is 65. The code for S is 83.
4. `83 - 65 + 1 = 19`, so `SEQUENCE(19,1,65,1)` creates an array containing the integers from 65 to 83, because it's a list with 19 rows, 1 column, starting at 65 and increasing by 1 step at a time.
5. `CHAR` converts the numeric code back to a character, so putting `CHAR(SEQUENCE(19,1,65,1))` creates a list of characters from A to S.
6. Concatenating the list mentioned in step 5 with the common characters in your range `"AB"&CHAR(...` then creates the required output.